# Workaround DECLARE statement in View

Tags: sql, database, dynamic-sql

I have the following which I would like to be a `View`, but the `Declare` statement is not allowed apparently.

What is the best solution/work-around to this problem?

I'm using SQL Server. I have tried many other solutions (Stored Procedures, Table-Values Functions), but I think the combination of Dynamic SQL is complicating the matter and I haven't been able to get anything working.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsAlias AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(MeasurementTypeID) 
            FROM dbo.Measurements
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SELECT @colsAlias = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(dbo.Measurements.MeasurementTypeID) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(dbo.MeasurementTypes.MeasurementType)  
    FROM dbo.Measurements INNER JOIN dbo.MeasurementTypes ON dbo.Measurements.MeasurementTypeID = dbo.MeasurementTypes.MeasurementTypeID
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT NeuronID, ' + @colsAlias +' FROM
(
SELECT MeasurementName, MeasurementValue, NeuronID, MeasurementTypeID
FROM dbo.Measurements
) x
PIVOT
(
MIN(MeasurementValue) FOR MeasurementTypeID IN (' + @cols + ')
) AS p'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Comment: Views cannot accept parameters (q.v. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956988/dynamic-sql-with-variables-inside-a-view-sql-server)), but a table valued function might be able to do what you want.

Comment: I agree that a Table-Valued Function would be the solution, as stated in the answer in the link your provided. HOWEVER, the problem then becomes knowing in advance the resulting Table - this is not possible since the table columns are generated dynamically. If you could provide a working example, that would be greatly appreciated.